# pandas filter out entire days of dataset based on value

Tags: python, pandas

If I have some made up data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint


np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

mediany= df.Value.median()
```

How could I filter the `df` based on filtering out ***entire days*** of data? For example for each day of data, if the average of `Value` is less than the entire average `Value` for entire dataset (`mediany`), discard this day..

I think I can filter out all data that is less than the average but this doesn't preserve complete days of data which I need.

```
df = df[(df[['Value']] >= mediany).all(axis=1)]

df
```

Any tips greatly appreciated hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform`:

```
s = (df['Value'].ge(mediany)            # compare to mediany
        .groupby(df.index.normalize())  # groupby day 
        .transform('any')               # any time with value larger than median
    )

df[s]
```

P/S: *the entire average Value for entire dataset (mediany)*, median is not average :-)

Comment: For newb here, I understand the difference between median & mean value of dataset... But whats the difference between mean & average?

Comment: Usually `mean` and `average` are the same things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I have added comments:-

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint


np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)
df["Date"] = df.index

#calculate day wise mean

def calculate_mean(x):
    return np.mean(x)

df_day_mean = df.groupby(df.index).agg({
        'Value': [('Value', calculate_mean)]
    })
df_day_mean.columns = df_day_mean.columns.droplevel()


#calculate whole mean

mean = df.Value.mean()

#get the days where average value is less than whole mean

df_to_discard = df_day_mean[df_day_mean["Value"]<mean]
index_to_discard = df_to_discard.index

# drop these indices from the original df

filtered_df = df.drop(index_to_discard)
```